# centralizers of nilpotent element in simple Lie algebra and associated Levi subalgebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $\{e,h,f\}$ be a $sl_2$ triples in simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak  g$ with usual relations $[h,e]=2e,~ [h,f]=-2f,~[e,f]=h$. Then the centralizer of $e$ is $\mathfrak g_e=\{b:[b,e]=0\}$ and the associated Levi subalgebra is $\mathfrak g_0=\{b:[b,h]=0\}$.  Is $\mathfrak g_0$ and $\mathfrak g_e$ are isomorphic  subalgebras?.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the answer is negative. Taking $\mathfrak{sl}_3(K)$ and $(e,f,h)$ given by 
$$
e=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\;
f=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\;
h=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & -1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\;
$$
I compute that $\dim \ker {\rm ad}(e)=4$ and $\dim \ker {\rm ad}(h)=2$, hence the two subalgebras have different dimension. We have ${\rm ad}(h)={\rm diag}(2,1,-2,-1,-1,1,0,0)$ and
$$
ad(e)=\begin{pmatrix} 0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &-2 & 1   \cr   
         0  &0  &0  &1  &0  &0  &0  &0  \cr
         0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0   \cr
         0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0   \cr
         0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0   \cr
         0  &0  &0  &0  &-1 &0  &0  &0   \cr
         0  &0  &1  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0   \cr
         0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0   \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: It's easier defining $e=E_{13}$, $f=E_{31}$, $h=E_{11}-E_{33}$. Then the centralizer of $h$ consists of diagonal matrices of trace, so has dimension 2, while the centralizer of $e$ consists of upper triangular matrices with $11$ and $33$ entries equal, hence of dimension $4$. In general, in an arbitrary semisimple Lie algebra and $sl_2$-triple, the centralizer of $e$ is reductive while that of $e$ is usually not.